# Is it possible to extract a function return type in C?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, macros

I am using the gcc compiler to compile a C program. The following code only prints the function name:

```
int main(void) {
  printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); // prints "main"
  printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);        // prints "main"
  printf("%s\n", __func__);            // prints "main"
  return 0;
}
```

whereas I want to print the function return type `int`. Is that possible?

**Update**: this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
typedef struct { 
  // ...                                               
  // data specific to A;                                                  
  uint32_t error;                                               
} StructA;

typedef struct {
  // ...
  // data specific to B
  uint32_t error;
}  StructB;

typedef struct {
  // ...
  // data specific to C
  uint32_t error;
} StructC;                  

#define CHECK(data, ReturnType)                             
{                                                               
  if (data.error) {                                         
    return (ReturnType) { .error = data.error };            
  }                                                             
}

// Returns either a success value or an error code
StructC build_c() { 
    StructA a = ...;
    CHECK(a, StructC); // want to avoid having to type StructC
    StructB b = ...;
    CHECK(b, StructC); // want to avoid having to type StructC
    return (StructC) { .data = a.data + b.data };
}
```

I want to have an error-handling macro that works for any struct type containing a field "error". In C++, you can make such macros work with `absl::StatusOr<Something>`. Is it possible to achieve something similar to **macros**+`absl::StatusOr<Something>` in C?

Comment: To make it more difficult, I don't have the function name. It's happening inside a macro, that's called within the function.

Comment: IMO it some kind XY problem

Comment: If the macro is invoked within the function, then you have the function name at the invocation point, so it can be passed as a parameter to the macro.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes, that's what I'm doing - passing the function return type. But it's unpleasant to write the type each time. I was looking for a way for a compiler to figure out the type automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the type (in GCC) - but you need to call the function.

```
char foo(void)
{
    return 'a';
}

double bar(void)
{
    printf("BAR\n");
    return 0.0;
}


#define ptype(x) _Generic((x), \
                        char: printf("char\n"), \
                        double: printf("double\n"))

int main(void)
{
    __auto_type a = foo();
    __auto_type b = bar();

    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(b));

    ptype(a);
    ptype(b);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Mej5azzhP

Comment: Thanks for showing an auto_type, this is closer to what's desired! I updated the question to explain my wish.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there may be an easier way to do this (eg, some compiler specific builtin), but you might get away with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define get_type(X) _Generic((X), \
    int (*)(void): "int",   \
    float (*)(void): "float",        \
    default: "??"       \
)

#define print_type(X) \
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", \
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, \
        __FUNCTION__, \
        __func__, \
        get_type(X) \
    );

int
foo(void) {
    print_type(foo);
    return 1;
}

float
bar(void) {
    print_type(bar);
    return 1.0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

If you have a lot of different function types, you'll get a combinatorial explosion of cases in the _Generic, but perhaps something like this is adequate.

Comment: 1. It does not give the type. 2. It only works for very specific parameters set (in this case `void`) https://godbolt.org/z/rxnvKdfdM He wanted something a bit more generic